# Open Google search screen with a word in it React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-search

I have a word in the web app. Let's say the word is food. Now, if the user clicks on the word, the Google search screen should open with the results of the word food searched.

[image]

I can redirect the user to the Google search screen with the help of

```js
    let win1 = window.open("//" + "google.com", '_blank');
```

But I am struggling to figure out how to pass the word in the search. Any suggestions on how to go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this, with term being a variable with what is being searched (i.e. food)

```
let win1 = window.open("//" + "google.com/search?q=" + term, '_blank');
```

Comment: Woah. And talk about simple things in life. Thanks! I was trying to figure out what google searches and somehow the URL constructed was very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Google accepts to search text using **Parameter** `q=`. You can just concat this parameter into your URL and try

```js
var searchText = 'food'
let win1 = window.open("//" + "google.com/search?q=" + searchText, '_blank');
```